# How to install/use django-inlinecss

Tags: django, plugins, settings, pip, django-inlinecss

I need to use [this plugin](https://github.com/roverdotcom/django-inlinecss) plugin in my app, but i have no idea about how to install and use it. So far, I have found [this fork](https://github.com/stevejalim/django-inlinecss) of the mentioned plugin that adds a `setup.py` script. After issuing the commands `python setup.py build` and `python setup.py install`, I added `'django_inlinecss'` to my `INSTALLED_APPS` setting, but still get the following error:

```
.
. (rest of the traceback)
.
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named django_inlinecss
```

How can I install this plugin and use it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, so I forked django-inlinecss original repostory and fixed the problem.

You can use

```
 pip install git+https://github.com/fjsj/django-inlinecss.git@18f2f8e5b5453f067dff0d6c0c2ae3066e56d554
```

to install it successfully. It was missing a `packages=find_packages(),` line in stevejalim's setup.py.

Comment: I've installed it by copying the project folder of inlineccs inside of my project, but i'd rather use your solution. What should I put on my requirements file so your fork could be installed with the rest of my project's dependencies, by running the command `pip install -r requirements.txt`? Thanks!

Comment: @Throoze you can put this line:
`git+https://github.com/fjsj/django-inlinecss.git@18f2f8e5b5453f067dff0d6c0c2ae3066e56d554`

Comment: I'm getting the following error: `Could not find a tag or branch '18f2f8e5b5453f067dff0d6c0c2ae3‌​066e56d554', assuming commit.
error: pathspec '"18f2f8e5b5453f067dff0d6c0c2ae3\342\200\214\342\200\213066e56d554"' did not match any file(s) known to git.` what is it? I checked your repo, and this is the right commit hash. any idea?

Comment: Are you sure you copied the line correctly? It looks like the are some unwanted backslashes there, so git is thinking it is a pathspec. And are you using `pip install -r requirements.txt`? I've just tested again and it worked with me. My pip version is 1.2.1 on Ubuntu 12.10. If it helps, here it is my whole requirements.txt file: https://gist.github.com/fjsj/de64ff155ee1c9e35843

Answer (score 4):

Sorry about the inconvenience - I didn't realize people had really started to use that library! (It's great to have people actually finding it useful by the way!)

Anyway, I've released it on Pypi, so you should now be able to just do a:

```
$ pip install django-inlinecss
```

If you have issues please open a ticket over at:

https://github.com/roverdotcom/django-inlinecss